# What should be put first in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions

> I'd like to use a large-scale experimental dataset, QQA-HTT.

Or

> I'd like to use QQA-HTT, a large-scale experimental dataset.

Which should be put first? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is phrased I gather that "QQA-HT" is more specific than "a large-scale dataset".

I would say it makes more sense to use the second option because it refers to the specific dataset (QQA-HT) and then explains to the uninformed reader that this dataset is "a large-scale experimental dataset".

The first option is more misleading, it reads as saying that the only possible "large-scale experimental dataset" is "QQA-HT", which is certainly untrue in the grand scheme of datasets.